# How to use LAST_INSERT_ID() when using uuid as a default value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I auto-generate a binary(16) Id by having this in my defaultExpression:

```
(uuid_to_bin(uuid(), true))
```

I created a store procedure and insert values to that table and figured I could retrive the latest value by using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` but Im getting the value `0` instead.

Example:

```
DECLARE userId BINARY(16);

INSERT INTO Users (Email, Password, FirstName, LastName, Age, Jobtitle, ImageId, PrefLang, ChangedPassword)
VALUES ('email', 'Hashpassword', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'age', 'jobTitle', 'imageId', 'prefLanguagId', 0);

SET userId = LAST_INSERT_ID(); // not getting the correct value here
```

Trying to use the value above in a junction table:

```
  INSERT INTO UserRoles (UserId, RoleId)
    VALUES (userId, roleId);
```

> Error Code: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`dbName`.`userroles`, CONSTRAINT `UserIdRef` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`Id`))

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can only use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` when using an auto increment column.

Comment: Im more use to working in a sql enviorment and thought it would be the same as IDENTIY. Only way to solve this is by adding the UUID manualy in the sp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` only gets an ID that was assigned using `AUTO_INCREMENT`. It won't return an ID that was assigned using a `DEFAULT` expression.

You'll need to calculate the ID in your procedure rather than using the default.

```
SET userId = uuid_to_bin(uuid(), true);
INSERT INTO Users (userId, Email, Password, FirstName, LastName, Age, Jobtitle, ImageId, PrefLang, ChangedPassword)
    VALUES (userId, 'email', 'Hashpassword', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'age', 'jobTitle', 'imageId', 'prefLanguagId', 0);
INSERT INTO UserRoles (UserId, RoleId)
    VALUES (userId, roleId);
```

Comment: Did not know that this was not possible. I firgured that the above would be solution as soon as I read you comment. Probably good to save this question a a future reference.